# Installing Ubuntu over Debian without losing /home data

Tags: system-installation, home-directory

I am currently running debian testing. I want to install the Ubuntu-Gnome distribution replacing Jessie but keep all my personal files in `/home` untouched.

Is it possible to do so if (I think) the `root` and `/home` live on different partitions on the HDD.

If yes, how?

Comment: you can make a seprate partition for installing ubuntu alongside debian so that your /home files are untouched

Comment: If they are different partitions, it's trivially easy. If not, you can choose not to format `/` when installing Ubuntu. Or install Ubuntu on a separate partition as Creator said, which is best of all.

Comment: If you are unsure if / and /home are on different partitions then post the output of `mount` here so someone can verify it for you. Be careful not to overwrite the wrong partition.

Comment: You can convert to a separate /home: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving BUT you should have full backups anyway and then you can restore from your backup.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do so if (I think) the root and /home live on
>   different partitions on the HDD.

You can install Ubuntu to the Debian root partition. After the install the system will reboot and you will have a fresh Ubuntu install. At this point you can add your /home partition in fstab to mount it. The advantage of doing it this way is that you get a clean install, and do not risk the installer overwriting your /home partition. Of course you have to make sure that you choose the Debian root partition to install to, and that you really do have /home and / on different partitions.